# BootCompleted Receiver not running

Tags: android

Hello I am new android developer. I create a sample project that works well when boot is completed.

Then I again create my main project to use this but boot completed not executed... I try my best to find problem.. I register this receiver through Manifest file not pragmatically...

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO: This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving
    // an Intent broadcast.
    Toast.makeText(context, "boot completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

and is Manifest XML

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.azmizryk.mobilethefttracker.BootCompleted"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
</receiver>
```

Comment: Have you manually started your app at least once using a 'launcher' `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following Intent actions in manifest.xml file.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

i.e. in your manifest file,change

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.azmizryk.mobilethefttracker.BootCompleted"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
    </receiver>
```

to

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.azmizryk.mobilethefttracker.BootCompleted"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
   <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: the following permission are not available  in my ADT.. and i mention that i tried in sample app same like i show here

Comment: i used this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

Comment: @user3001551 RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED is the permission which you need to add,and BOOT_COMPLETED is the intent action which broadcast once, after the system has finished booting.

Comment: @user3001551 BOOT_COMPLETED and QUICKBOOT_POWERON are broadcast intent action not permissions,so change your code as I suggested,it will work.

Comment: @user3001551 happy to help,enjoy coding.